# ConTeXt table row vertical fill page

Tags: context, context-mkiv

Is there a way to have a `bTR` for ConTeXt fill a page vertically?

I want to have a full-page table, with both width and height filled.

Given e.g.

```
\bTABLE
 \bTR \bTD One \eTD \eTR
 \bTR \bTD Vertically Filled! \eTD \eTR
\eTABLE
```

How can one have the `Vertically Filled` row take up the balance of the page (bearing in mind that the first row has variable height, but never more than 50% of the height of the page).

Answer (score 2):

My solution might not be exactly what you ask for, but works for me. I divide tables in fractions of \textwidth and \textheight and manually set them for each table.

```
\starttext
\bTABLE 
\setupTABLE[r][1][width=\textwidth,height=0.4\textheight]
\setupTABLE[r][2][width=\textwidth,height=0.6\textheight]
 \bTR \bTD  One \eTD \eTR
 \bTR \bTD Vertically Filled! \eTD \eTR
\eTABLE 
\stoptext
```